# How to return json list result in IENumerable type viewbag MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to get list result in `IENumerable` type `ViewBag` that contains already a list before.

I am returning list using viewbag in action-

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RangerCard() {
    var taglist = (from u in db.TagTables
                   where u.TagName.Contains(tag)
                   select u).ToList();

    ViewBag.TagName = taglist;
    return View();

}
```

**Returing List-**

```
   @if (ViewBag.TagName != null) {
       foreach (var item in ViewBag.TagName) {
           <p class="tag-division">
               <a id="@item" class="tag-in-dropdown" href="#"># @item</a>
           </p>
       }
  }
```

**It looks like-**

[image]

This action return all the tags in a dropdown menu. Now I wanted to filter this result as soon as a user writes in this textbox.

In case of tagName `RipEnglish`-

I am filtering tags according to this text using ajax query-

`#cardhascode` is id of input textbox.

```
   $('#cardhashcode').keyup(function () {
       var tag = $('#cardhashcode').val();
       $.ajax({
           url: '/Upload/JsonTagList/?tag=' + tag,
           type: 'Post',
           success: function (data) {

           }
       });
  });
```

And then **action-**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonTagList(string tag) {
    var taglist = (from u in db.TagTables
                   where u.TagName.Contains(tag)
                   select u).ToList();
    return Json(taglist);
}
```

This above action filters tag but I am not able to deal with output result. How do I show this filter result in this dropdown menu as filtered result.

**Note-**

This result is coming in list type. So there can be more than one tag available On every `keyup` event.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: on success made new markup and past it in container of your dropdown

Comment: you need to mess up with jQuery here, or i recommend return Partial view, that contain filtered tags, and paste that html string to container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this inside your success handler:

```
if(data){
    data.forEach(function(item){
        $('#yourtagcontainer').append('<p class="tag-division"><a id="'+item+'" class="tag-in-dropdown" href="#"># '+item+'</a></p>');
    });
}
```

Cheers.